# Python Exception <NameError>: name 'feature' is not defined in a PythonCaller

Tags: python, fme-form

I'm trying to set up a simple [`PythonCaller`](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pythoncaller.htm) in FME (2020.2.4.0) but it's not working properly.

Here's what is written in the PytonCaller, it's simply taken from the official example:

```python
import fme
import fmeobjects

import numpy as np
print(f"numpy version: {np.__version__}")

# Template Function interface:
# When using this function, make sure its name is set as the value of
# the 'Class or Function to Process Features' transformer parameter
def processFeature(feature):
    pass

# Template Class Interface:
# When using this class, make sure its name is set as the value of
# the 'Class or Function to Process Features' transformer parameter
class FeatureProcessor(object):
    """Docstring
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.featureList = []

    def input(self,feature):
        print(type(feature))
    
    def close(self):
        self.pyoutput(feature)
```

Please note that it is connected to a transformer (AttributeManager) which actually has many output features, and they show up on the mini map in the Visual Preview.

Here's the relevant part of the log, the numpy version is printed so the PythonCaller was executed:

```
2021-07-16 14:40:58| 1.9| 0.2|INFORM|numpy version: 1.15.1
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.0| 0.1|STATS |FeatureHolder (SortFactory): Output 298 feature(s) without doing any sorting
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.0| 0.0|STATS |FeatureHolder_OUTPUT Feature Counter -1 40 (TeeFactory): Cloned 298 input feature(s) into 298 output feature(s)
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.2| 0.2|WARN |Python Exception <NameError>: name 'feature' is not defined
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.2| 0.0|WARN |Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 27, in close
NameError: name 'feature' is not defined
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.2| 0.0|FATAL |PythonCaller (PythonFactory): PythonFactory failed to close properly
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.2| 0.0|ERROR |PythonCaller (PythonFactory): A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
2021-07-16 14:40:59| 2.2| 0.0|ERROR |PythonCaller (PythonFactory): A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
```

FME version info (on a Windows server):

```
FME Information
Edition: FME ESRI Edition (node locked-crc)
Version: FME(R) 2020.2.4.0 (20210304 - Build 20825 - WIN64)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Server 4.0 64-bit (Build 9600)
```

Did you ever experienced such issue?
Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `close` method does not have `feature` input and your code, as it stands, has no stored knowledge of any feature.

Below is the official example modified to include what you are seeming to try and do (this is most likely assumption based upon your question).  It stores all the features in a list and then outputs them all 'en masse' when the transformer is closed.

```
class FeatureProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #initialise the list
        self.featureList = []

    def input(self,feature):
        #output to log the object type of the feature
        print(type(feature))
        #add the feature to the end of the list array
        self.featureList.append(feature) 

    def close(self):
        #loop through all stored features
        for feature in self.featureList:
            #output current feature to next transformer
            self.pyoutput(feature)
```

The advantage I can see to doing this is - you appear to want to write further Python code to process the whole dataset as one, before outputting to the next transformer.